# User coming back null even in if statement

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can't figure out why my `userId` String is coming back `null`. Please help.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    carName = intent.getStringExtra("carname");

    //get current user
    if (auth.getCurrentUser().getUid() != null) {
        userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }
    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AUTH STATE SIGNED IN");
                userId = user.getUid();
                getCarName();
                mDatabaseReference.child("cars").setValue(userId);
            } else {
                //User is Signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "AUTH STATE SIGNED OUT");
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);

    //set views
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView carNameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.car_name);
    final TextView carAddressTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.car_notes);
    final TextView carCountTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
    plusOneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIn);
    minusOneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOut);
    signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
    editCar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_car_button);



    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cars").child(userId);
```

I was able to get around it by adding this `if` statement before the listener. I would just prefer not to have it look like that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you determining that `user.getUid()` is null?

Comment: Because i get this error when trying to access the database reference java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() ------ this is what i put next mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bars").child(userId);

Comment: Post the code that contains `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bars").‌​child(userId)` so we can see the context.

Comment: edited -- is that what youre looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [onAuthStateChanged()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) callback is asynchronous.  Is does not fire with a valid userID until the user is signed-in.

The statement:

```
 mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cars").child(userId);
```

is executing before `userId` has been assigned a value in the listener callback.

Comment: how would you suggest I fix this?

Comment: Can't really answer that without knowing your overall UI flow.  Have you looked at the [Auth Quickstart Project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) as example of auth UI?

Comment: Another option is to use [Firebase-UI Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md).